# How to display the name of a user logged in with Google Sign In and Firebase in another UIViewController

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-signin

I have a question. 
Firebase DATABASE:

```
 {
  "Users" : {
    "109015298583739078046" : {
      "Name" : "Manuel Schiavon"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to display the name "Manuel Schiavon" in another UIViewController but  I don't know how. Now the name it's Manuel Schiavon but it's only an example so if another user logs into my app (with Google Sign in) should see his name on the screen not the mine.

THIS IS MY APP DELEGATE.SWIFT

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import GoogleSignIn

@UIApplicationMain

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    FirebaseApp.configure()

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self

    return true
}

func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,
                                         sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
                                         annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])

}
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,
                                             sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
                                             annotation: annotation)

}
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error?) {
    // ...
    if error != nil {
        // ...
        return
    }
    print("L'utente è entrato in Google")

    guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return }
    let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken,
                                                   accessToken: authentication.accessToken
                                                              )

    // ...
    Auth.auth().signInAndRetrieveData(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in
        if error != nil {
            // ...
            return
        }
        // User is signed in
        // ...
        let userID: String = user.userID
        let userName: String = user.profile.name

        Database.database().reference().child("Users").child(userID).setValue(["Name": userName])//Salva il nome in Firebase
        self.window?.rootViewController?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "HomeSegue", sender: self) //Per andare al secondo screen, "HomeSegue è il nome del collegamento tra il UIViewController 1 e 2.
    }

    print ("L'utente è entrato in Firebase")

}

func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didDisconnectWith user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
    // Perform any operations when the user disconnects from app here.
    // ...
}


func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}


}
```

THIS IS MY VIEWCONTROLLER.SWIFT

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import GoogleSignIn

class ViewController: UIViewController, GIDSignInUIDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var LB_username: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

THIS IS MY STORYBOARD
[Click here to see the storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYQzY.png)
pls help me! Thanks!

Comment: You've included a link to a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: Ok thanks, is it ok now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit 2 - Now I see the code**

Add this in viewDidLoad of your ViewController and forget what we said so far.

```
        if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
            if let name = Auth.auth().currentUser?.displayName {
                LB_username.text = name
                }
            }
```

**Edit - "where and how should I declare userName? Short answer"**

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var userId: String?
    var userName: String?
    //...
```

"I don't know how to handle optionals" - In this case, do this:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var userId = String()
    var userName = String()
    //...
```

**Old Answer**

Your answer is not clear, so I try to guess what you want to achieve:

- Assuming you already have your name stored in `userName`, as I can see here:

  `Database.database().reference().child("Users").child(userID).setValue(["Name": userName])`

what you want to do is to pass this string in your "HomeSegue" segue.
To do this you need to implement prepare for segue method

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621490-prepare

Here's an example:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
{

    if segue.identifier == "HomeSegue" {
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as! MySecondViewController
        destinationVC.myLabel.text = userName
    }
}
```

Note: 
 - userName needs to be global
 - myLabel is a property of MySecondViewController

Comment: Thanks so much! But sorry I have another question.  "userName needs to be global" ehm how? Ah do I have to put the CODE you gave me in "AppDelegate" or "ViewController"? Sorry for my stupid questions but I started programming 2 weeks ago.... so I am a beginner

Comment: It is a good question. See, you declare two constants inside `sign` function, that means that `userId` and `userName` cannot be used outside that function. In your AppDelegate you can find `var window: UIWindow?` is an optional but it is declared outside any function, that means you can access from anywhere to it. So, what you want to do is to declare your constants as var (or optional) strings outside any functions

Comment: Your answer was very clear!, thanks   This is what I wrote:                                                                                            class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var userID: String = user.userID
    var userName: String = user.profile.name  >PROBLEM "Use of unresolved identifier 'user' "

Comment: see my edited answer and let me know if it works now

Comment: See my answer, I uploaded two images to let you understand better the problem

Comment: see edit, I changed approach. Now you use Auth instead of using variables stored in AppDelegate. If it doesn't work you might want create a Singleton, but try my edit first.

Comment: have you tried `LB_username?.text = name` (see the question mark). If it doesn't work, try to give us more information about your label.

Comment: IT WORKS(with the "?")! Thanks a lot @mrfcal to help me with this problem!

Comment: I added another question. If you have time, can you help me? I ask this to you 'cause I noticed that you are a very good iOS developer

Comment: Please, don't use answer as question. You are asking how to do something that is not related to the previous question so you can create a new one. Also, describe where the image is stored and if you are not able to download it or to set the image view.

Comment: Ok sorry now I'm going to create a new question